# S3 SDK updating a single object when uploading instead of creating a new file

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to just upload as many files I want to a S3 bucket usign the Java SDK. I'm doing it as follows:

```
    @Override
public void upload() {
    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, ACCESS_KEY, new File('myFilePath'));
    getS3Client().putObject(putObjectRequest);
}
```

The problem is that it is ALWAYS overriding and existing file. So, no matter if I change the "myFilePath" parameter, to an image or a text, it doesn't create a new file but updates an existing one. It shouldn't happen because these are different files, not the same.

How can I just create a file without updating an existing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to the PutObjectRequest constructor is the key under which to store the new object. You are mistakenly passing the same key (ACCESS_KEY) for all the requests.

Answer (score 1):

The S3 key is the name of the object. It is the full path + filename of the file in S3. You are using ACCESS_KEY which looks like part of your AWS credentials. You shouldn't be passing the ACCESS_KEY in that parameter, you should be passing the object key/file name.